# Using Photoshop's scratch disk

Tags: performance, adobe-photoshop

What is the best way of setting up a machine to utlize Photoshop's scratch disk feature. I am using Photoshop CS2 with a machine with three hard drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick your fastest internal drive. 
If they are all similar then go with the first partition of the OS drive.

If you are running the second two drives in a raid then use those. 
Basically the idea is to put photoshop's scratch location on the fastest disk or partition.